# Not able to parse the date in US format in java

Tags: java, date

I have the below java program in which you specify the parameter in which format you want to convert date that is whether you want to convert it in US or UK format.

Now the problem is that when i want date to be formatted as per US format it does not do that , request you to please advise what is missing in this format ,below is program and output which is there when i try to convert it in US format

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils;


public class DateFormattingTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        System.out.println ("01-Mar-2016-->" + extractDate("01-Mar-2016",  "US") );

    }




    public static java.util.Date extractDate(String dateStr, String dateType) {

        java.util.Date date = null;


        if (!dateStr.matches("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}")){

            String[] datePatternsOfUk = { "d-M-yy", "d-M-yyyy", "d/M/yy", "d/M/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd","dd-MM-yy", "dd-MMM-yy","dd-MMM-yyyy","dd-MM-yyyy",
                    "dd/MM/yy","dd/MMM/yy","dd/MMM/yyyy"};
            String[] datePatternsOfUs = { "M-d-yy","MM-dd-yy","M/d/yy","MM/dd/yy", "MM/dd/yy", "MMM-dd-yy",
                    "MMM/dd/yy", "MMM-dd-yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy", "MMM/dd/yyyy",
                    "MM/dd/yyyy" };
            String[] datePatterns = datePatternsOfUk;

            try {   
        if (dateType.equals("US")) {
            datePatterns = datePatternsOfUs;
        } else if (dateType.equals("UK")) {
            datePatterns = datePatternsOfUk;
        }
            int p = dateStr.lastIndexOf("/");
        if (p == -1) {
            p = dateStr.lastIndexOf("-");
        }
        String firstSubstring = dateStr.substring(0, p + 1);
        String secondSubstring = dateStr.substring(p + 1);
        if (p != -1 && secondSubstring.length() <= 2) {
            secondSubstring = Integer.toString(2000 + Integer.parseInt(secondSubstring));
            dateStr = firstSubstring + secondSubstring;
        }

            date = DateUtils.parseDate(dateStr, datePatterns);
        } catch (ParseException e) {


        } 
        return date;
        }



        if (dateStr.matches("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}")){
            try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String convertedCurrentDate =sdf.format(sdf.parse(dateStr));

                date=sdf.parse(convertedCurrentDate);
            } catch (ParseException e) {


            }
            return date;
        }
        return null;
                }

   }
```

The output that i am getting on US format is shown below..

```
01-Mar-2016-->null
```

Actually in US format i am expecting the date to be display as

```
01-Mar-2016--> 3-Jan-2016
```

folks please advise for this is my expected result is not correct one as per US format

Answer (score 1):

`01-Mar-2016` isn't in a format you have defined for US. Add `dd-MMM-yyyy` to `datePatternsOfUs` like

```
String[] datePatternsOfUs = { "M-d-yy","MM-dd-yy","M/d/yy","MM/dd/yy",
        "MM/dd/yy", "MMM-dd-yy", "MMM/dd/yy", "MMM-dd-yyyy", 
        "MM-dd-yyyy", "MMM/dd/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy", "dd-MMM-yyyy" };
```

Comment: well i have added this string entirely at the end "d-M-yy", "d-M-yyyy", "d/M/yy", "d/M/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd","dd-MM-yy", "dd-MMM-yy", "dd-MMM-yyyy"

Comment: but still as per my analysis when i am selecting US format don't you think the date 01-Mar-2016 should be displayed as 3-Jan-2016 in US format as US fromat is mm-dd--yyyy

Comment: How is two digit month the same as the month name abbreviation? MMM != M

Comment: still not able to grasp please

Comment: @sdsdsds From [the class doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)… Month: If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number.